# Dynamic basedir for Ant in Eclipse

Tags: ant

The title might not be the best so let me explain what I am trying to do.

I have made an Ant buildfile that will help me with Maven goals. It's so much easier having to scope to Ant view and choose what I want to do. The biggest benefit with this is that I can use it in almost any project. Whether I deploy to tomcat or jboss or sakai(:deploy) or I handle mutiple instaces of the same server or skip tests... worst case I just change some path properties.

The drawback right now is that I have to keep a copy of this buildfile in every project.

What I am trying to do is have only 1 buildfile, in the workspace, and dinamicaly optain, from eclipse, the current project that I am working on. Be it module or parent I can refine that later.
So basically change the basedir for ant tasks based on the selected project in eclipse.

I have tried Ant Runtime Properties but for some reason properties like

> ${project_path}

fail to give me what their description say. I get this:

> Variable references empty selection: ${project_path}

I hope it is clear what I am trying to do. So my question, I know it's possible, I'm just missing something and I hope some of you can help me with this.

I believe the trouble is in the Ant Runtime properties. I'm not 100% sure how I should use those.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT** after comment and further investigation..
Make the projectdir available as basedir property for ant like that :
`Window > Preferences > Ant > Runtime > Properties`
and create a property named basedir with value either :

`${project_loc}`
or
`${workspace_loc}/${project_name}`

and

```
<project basedir="${basedir}">
 <echo>$${basedir} = ${basedir}</echo>
</project>
```

will work as expected, means echoing eclipse/yourworkspace/projectdir

Maybe there are other ways, i.e. via [Ant Addon Ant4Eclipse](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/), which aims to make Eclipse settings available for ant, never used it.

Comment: If I understand correct this means I will need to change `NameOfYourProject` only once, when I add a new project. While this might work it's not exactly what I want. Thank you for your response.


Let me underline what I don't understand and I believe it will help me find the answer: _Why doesn't eclipse know the current project I am working on and gives me `Variable references empty selection: ${project_path}` when I use ${project_path} or ${project_loc}?_

Comment: works for me in Eclipse 3.7.1 with WindowsXP/32bit/jdk1.6.0_30 and Windows7/64bit/jdk1.7.0_02 and also in Eclipse 3.6.2 with OpenSuse11.4/64bit/1.6.0_29 I don't get any message like "variable references ..." Questions : How do you start your ant file in Eclipse ? Which OS, Eclipse version, java version ?

Comment: I start it from Ant View. I have added the build file there. I just pick the task I want to run and dclick. Right now I am using Java 1.5_18 and Eclipse Classic 3.4.1. Upgrading is not an option since I am working on an old Sakai tool. I did try a newer version of java and Eclipse Indingo but I had weird results after deploying the tool .

Comment: Can't reproduce that, whether starting via Editor/Run As Ant Build or Ant Outline or Ant View - all works as expected !?

Comment: Even thought I still didn't make it work on my current environment, I accepted your answer because you've confirmed that above way to use ant runtime properties works. So I will start from that and rebuild.

Comment: I used this technique on a build.xml file that someone else created and I needed to override where they were specifying the basedir. I simply made a property under the Ant runtime preference called basedir and set it to my local directory where I had the project checked out via subversion.