# What are project scoped Ant variables in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ant, properties

If I open

```
Windows->Preferences->Ant->Runtime->Properties
```

in Eclipse, I can see global properties for Ant.

Do I have some sort of "local" properties, like workspace directory or project directory? How to see or set them?

I have created new empty build.xml in some project and want to add some automation into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on build.xml -> Run As -> Ant Build...

Click on the Properties tab, you should be able to opt to use project specific properties here.

Answer (score 1):

See this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9378934/130683) for an example of using a 'local' eclipse property like i.e. `${project_loc}` in ant. There's also [Ant Addon Ant4Eclipse](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/), which aims to make Eclipse settings available for ant.